# Angular directive not binding expression with version migration

Tags: angularjs

Im new to angular and im facing following issue after angular version migration. We migrate from version 1.2.6 to version 1.4.3. Following is, sample code which was implemented using angular ver 1.2.6;

code done with angular 1.2.6 version.

--- JSP ---

```
<div>
<span call-test config="testConfig.test1" status="getStatus" value="testValue"></span>                                  
</div>
.
.
.
<div>                           
<span call-test config="testConfig.test2" status="getStatus" value="testValue"></span>
</div>
```

--- testCtrl.js ---

```
$scope.testConfig = {
    test1 : {name: "Test1", type: 0},
    test2 : {name: "Test2", type: 1}
};
.
.
.

$scope.getStatus = function(arg){
switch(arg) {
        case 1 :

            return (validate $scope.arg and return true or false);
        case 2 :

            return (validate $scope.arg and return true or false);
        case 0 :

            return (validate $scope.arg and return true or false);
        default :

            return false;
    }
}
```

--- testDirective.js----

```
angular.module('com.test.directives', [])
.directive('callTest', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

var callTest = function(element, scope){

    $timeout(function(){
        var statusAction = scope.status(scope.config.type);// bind value only for first span. but works fine if we pass 'scope.config'.

    }, 100);

};

return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{
            config:'=',
            status:'&'          
},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           var statusAction = scope.status();
           scope.$watch('value', function(){
               callTest(element, scope);
           });

        }
    };
}]);
```

I believe something not correct with 'testDirective.js'. What happens here is, 'status' only binding for first span only. Please share your valuable thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

@Navin can you check it like scope["config"].type and see??